# Synchronize databases in .NET

Tags: windows, library, database, synchronization

I develop an application with .NET that uses a MS SQL-Server database for storing. I can also work offline with a local copy of the Data (using MS LocalDB).

Now I want to synchronize the data when getting online again. I know I could just code all of that but there must be a library that already does all that for me.

Which one and how to use it?

Comment: @@juergen-d If I understood your question correctly have you looked into Microsoft sync framework ?

Comment: I had only a real quick look at it and asked myself if there is a more simple solution to this. But I guess I can do it with Sync Framework if there is no better alternative.

Comment: @@juergen-d You should check http://sourceforge.net/projects/symmetricds/ It's a software for both file and database synchronization with support for multi-master replication, filtered synchronization, and transformation across the network in a heterogeneous environment.

Comment: @@juergen-d Let me if my answer worked for you :),So I can post it as the answer here :)

Comment: What budget? WorkSmarter's answer is valid if you don't mention a budget.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: For free and whos answer?

Comment: @juergend: WorkSmarter deleted his/her answer after you commented that 600$ is too much.

Answer (score -2):

You can look at [Siaqodb](http://siaqodb.com), you can synchronize local Siaqodb with MS SQLServer and it works for mostly all .NET platforms including Xamarin.

Comment: It does not seem to work with MS LocalDB.